# Dynamically change router file Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a website using Symfony2 and I'd like to have a completely different routing file depending of the user (ip address, ...)

My first idea was to load a different environment if function of the user, but the kernel (so the environment setup) is set before the events, I think this solution can't work.

I want to keep the same url, no redirection on another website ...

If you have any idea, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create extra loader which will extend your existing loaders like in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html). In your case:

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Routing;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class AdvancedLoader extends Loader
{
    private $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        $collection = new RouteCollection();

        $ip = $this->request->getClientIp();

        if($ip == '127.0.0.1'){
            $resource = '@AppBundle/Resources/config/import_routing1.yml';
        }else{
            $resource = '@AppBundle/Resources/config/import_routing2.yml';
        }

        $type = 'yaml';

        $importedRoutes = $this->import($resource, $type);

        $collection->addCollection($importedRoutes);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return 'advanced_extra' === $type;
    }
}
```

---

## AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
   app.routing_loader:
       class: AppBundle\Routing\AdvancedLoader
       arguments: [@request=]
       tags:
           - { name: routing.loader }
```

---

## app/config/routing.yml

```
app_advanced:
    resource: .
    type: advanced_extra
```

Comment: It works, but the route is directly add in cache, but you can disable the cache with http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/apache_router.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PHP file as your main router and then depending on your conditions (user, IP, ...) you could load dynamic routes or load individual routing files.

Going by http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html you could set up your routing like this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    router: { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.php" }
```

In the routing.php file you can import static files (yml, xml) or just register the routes directly there (all of this based on your specific conditions).